# What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: display-suite

I do not know what this "notice" means:

> Notice: Undefined index: content in ds_render_block_field() 
>   (line 947 of
>   /home/magpie/public_html/mysite.com/sites/all/modules/ds/ds.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: content in ds_render_block_field() (line 947
>   of
>   /home/magpie/public_html/mysite.com/sites/all/modules/ds/ds.module).

I am tempted to just delete the line but I think it is best to check first and verify that it is not important.

Can somebody help explain how errors like this occur? And how to prevent them and deal with them?

Comment: When and how do you get this error?

Comment: It comes up on the admin panel and it has been ther ea while so I am not able to trace it's origin temporally

Comment: Modules should not use array indexes which are not set. This is a bug in the module, and per [FAQ] the question is off-topic for Drupal Answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To check what errors mean, you can use Google.  Here's how.

Search for the error message inside double quotes (" ") but don't search for the whole message, just the part up to the line number (why: line numbers may be different depending on the site and you won't get any hits.)  Searching inside double quotes forces Google to only match pages that have the exact phrase inside the quotes.

In this case, make a search like this:

> "Notice: Undefined index: content in ds_render_block_field()"

[The first result is an issue explaining the problem on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1292324).

That issue shows that the problem is with the Display Suite module.  If you read through the issue linked above, you will find a link to [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1279478), which is a bug report.  Reading this issue shows that the bug was fixed in a dev version of Display Suite.  So, to fix the problem, you should be able to update to the latest dev version of the Display Suite module.

Answer (score 0):

It's a notice, not a big deal to make you worry as it says, there is an undefined line in your display suit module

Comment: how should I define it?

Comment: This is not exact: There is an undefined array index, not an undefined line.